I still couldn't use os-probe
I enable the os-probe but it still doesn't work.


This is likely the explanation

You're not running the correct command, call up os-prober with no arguments to scan all available disks on the system for other operating systems, and output a list of strings that a bootloader like grub can consume to create boot entries.

As per your query above: You're not running the correct command. Call up os-prober with no arguments to scan all available disks on the system for other operating systems, and output a list of strings that a bootloader like grub can consume to create boot entries.
Secondly, the assumption made above from your question is that for some reason, your bootloader is not finding alternate operating systems present on your computer's drives.
This implies that despite the presence of os-prober, grub-specific components such as grub-mount (which os-prober explicitly depends on) are not executing properly.
The grub-mount package depends on the presence of the fuse3 package, without which it fails silently.
This is something you can verify via either apt-rdepends for reverse dependency look-up and/or a combination of both debtree and the dot commands to print out a dependency graph.
A very quick way to check for the presence or absence of fuse3 is by calling up:
sudo find / -name libfuse3.so.3 2> /dev/null

And then fix the broken installation by installing fuse3:
sudo apt-get -y install fuse3

Test and report back.
